# It must be possible to include a ListView inside a ListView using BaseAdapter right?

Tags: android, android-listview

This question exactly demonstrates my problem.
[How to nest ListViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391508/how-to-nest-listviews)

The provided answers are not acceptable.  I already have a layout I need to populate that is quite customized and everything is working aside from the fact that my child `ListView` only populates the first item on the list.

I guess I can't figure out why the second `ListView` called from the nested `BaseAdapter` won't work.  In addition, it's been three years since this question was asked and I wonder if anything has changed, or if new eyes on it can provide a solution.  again, the provided answers just don't present the data as I would like to have it.  I really need a custom xml layout, not an `ExpandableListAdapter`.  Also, the child lists will only have 2-5 items, so scrolling in the child items, really should not be an issue..

Any thoughts, or suggestions?

Comment: If the number of cells in the parent `ListView` is insignificant, you can use a vertically oriented `LinearLayout` with child `ListView`s.

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Read the answers again, especially considering CommonsWare's answer suggesting something like his `MergeAdapter`. This would let you use your existing custom layout.

Comment: okay.  Last night I actually just constructed the layout dynamically using inflater and adding the child views to a parent vertical LinearLayout.  It seems to work fine. Thanks for taking the time to respond.